# on message event make my bot don't working

Tags: python, discord.py

My commands don't work and I think it's because of the `on_message` event. When it checks if message is in the good channel, it actually "steel" the command so my bot commands are not triggered but I don't know how to fix that

```py
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)
defrole = ""
cmdchannels = ["none"]
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('.help'))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=defrole))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in cmdchannels :
        await message.delete()
            
@bot.command()
async def setcmd(ctx, arg):
    global cmdchannels
    cmdchannels.append(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=arg).id)
    print(cmdchannels)
    await ctx.send(arg+' is now defined as a cmd/bot channel !')

@bot.command()
async def defaultrole(ctx):
    global defrole
    defrole = str(ctx.message.role_mentions[0])
    await ctx.send(defrole+' is now the default on join role !')
bot.run("Token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` event blocks your commands from working. In order to prevent this, you have to process commands.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in cmdchannels :
        await message.delete()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to process the commands, add this line at the end of your `on_message` function:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Reference: [`process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)